# Newrelic API v2 App Instance Details

Tags: api, newrelic

I'm looking to find out if there is an equivalent mapping, as exists in the NewRelic REST API v1 that allows you to get throughput, apdex, summary data, etc. for an individual app instance for a particular host in the V2 api.

For example, I'd imagine the URL scheme would look something like:

```
    curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications.json' \
        -H 'X-Api-Key:INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY'
        -d 'filter[ids]=AppID_hServerInstanceId'
```

The AppId_hServerInstanceId is the scheme that's allowed in V1 to pull down app data for a particular instance.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time there is no way to query on the instance xxxx_iyyyy , as seen from JVMs, or for hosts xxxx_hyyyy as seen for applications running on multiple hosts. Specifying an instance or host in the V2 API Explorer will result in an error. Using them in the V2 query will cause the instance or host specification to be truncated and the application value will be returned.

This has been reported as a problem in the new Data API and will be addressed in a future release.